# I have 1.8 Jar and want to compile in 1.6

Tags: java, jar

I want to compile 1.8 jar in 1.6 but it giving error class file has wrong version. 
How to compile 1.8 jar in 1.6?

Comment: "*How to compile 1.8 jar in 1.6?*" - Normally, jars are already compiled. You cannot "re-compile" them if you do not have the sources. Why do you use Java 1.6 anyways? Java SE 6 is more than 10 years old.

Comment: Is the java 8 code used inside that jar?

Comment: RetroLambda (https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) supports backporting of lambdas, they also list references to two other utilities that can backport streams and the time API.